# Turn off/on vs Keep running: which gives longer lifespan?

Tags: hardware-failure, power, shutdown, hibernate, lifespan

Powering off a PC component, and powering it on, are stressful events that may lower its lifespan. In my own experience, long lasting components almost never broke mid-use. Rather, once turned off, they would never turn on again. So I became a bit paranoid about shutting down things. They may never turn on again. Instead, I just keep them running. Seems a much safer choice.

But reading online, everyone advises to turn off, or hibernate, the computer while not in use. My own experience tells me this is actually worse, as it forces the components through this stressful events more often.

So I ask, **what is truly worse for the health of a component while not in use. To keep it running, or to power it off/hibernate, and later on/wake?**

Note: The electricity bill is of no concern to me. Only the lifespan of my components.

Answer (score 0):

I have two laptops and a desktop (Lenovo). I have a number of precision instruments in my basement workshop, some newer, some older, one uses vacuum tubes and works nicely. All of these can be turned off without any damage to the device or longevity of the components.

If the computer is good quality, you can leave it running or turn it off at your discretion. Neither action should cause any issue or any major change in lifespan.

Your concern is valid but good workstation and laptop computers are made to turn off when not in use (e.g. overnight).